# How to pass Paper.set() to another Javascript in my case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael, jquery-events

I have a index.html page, which contains a button`id="my-btn"`

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>My INDEX PAGE</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="my-canvas"></div>
        <br><input type="button" id="my-btn" value="OPEN NEW WINDOW"/>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
        <script src="js/raphael.js"></script>
        <script src="js/my-graph.js"></script>
        <script src="js/my.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

***js/my.js*** invoke `createCircle` function from ***my-graph.js***, and handles button click event, when `my-btn` button is clicked, a new browser window will be popped up with a new page (**test.html**)

**my.js:**

```
    MyTest.createCircle();
    $('#my-btn').click(function(){  
      window.open('test.html', 'testwindow');
    });
```

**my-graph.js:**

```
MyTest= function(){
    
     var paper = Raphael("my-canvas", 320, 200);
         var st=paper.set();
    
    return {
       createCircle: function(){
                st.push(
                   paper.circle(10, 10, 5),
                   paper.circle(30, 10, 5)
                 );

                
            }
       getSet: function(){
                 return st;
        }   

    };
        
        
}();
```

The new page(***test.html***) opened in new browser window:

**test.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="my-name"></div>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/my-graph.js"></script>
    <script src="js/test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the new page, ***test.js*** will be invoked and I want to pass the **Paper.set()** `st` from ***my-graph.js*** to this test.js and output `st.length` as the content of this page

**js/test.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var st=MyTest.getSet();
    $("#my-name").append("<strong>"+st.length+"</strong>");
});
```

But I always get 0 length of the st in new popped up page. Why?

Answer (score 0):

so your opening a new page with script references to the same code
as the other page

That dosent mean that they have the same state.
The new page will get its own state from evaluating
the script itself

what you can do is save the reference that

```
 var w = window.open('test.html', 'testwindow');
```

returns you can use that for calling a function on your new page

or you can yost do all the code on the start page with jquery
and useing that window object as your context

```
var w = window.open('test.html', 'testwindow');
$(w).ready(function() {
  $("body", w).append(mystuff);
});
```

raphael objects are set to a paper i think not shure what will
happend when passing them betwen papers :S